# Wordpress 8 page-{slug}.php is not working?

Tags: wordpress

I upgrade Wordpress 8. an then create a new page testing.

slug of this page is testing so i create a new file in theme direcory.

page-testing.php

and then i run testing is not comming on page-testing.php file.

please help.

thank you.

Comment: So, if this is not working then it means that page.php template is being used to display this page. Right?

Comment: Be sure that the template of the testing page is default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong because very little information is provided. But I guess that if you have a custom page template set then that is the problem. As per WordPres Template Hierarchy. The priority is as follows:-

```
Page display

Template file used to render a static page (page post-type)

1. custom template file - The Page Template assigned to the Page. See get_page_templates().
2. page-{slug}.php - If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use page-recent-news.php
3. page-{id}.php - If the page ID is 6, WordPress will look to use page-6.php
4. page.php
5. index.php
```

source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 4):

4 years later I had the same issue and finally got an actual explanation why this happens.

To all those lost souls:

> **If your Wordpress Page slug is less than 6 characters long the custom page templates won't work.**

Comment: This sounds very specific, but it worked for me anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I made page-{slug}.php with a 4 character word and it works perfectly. Using wordpress 5

Answer (score 0):

I was not been able to show my personalized page because I had to config my permalink in settings > permalinks and change the common settings from "plain" to "post name", then in pages > permalink > URL slug. Changing it my page worked just fine.